# How to Read Fetched Objects in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I'm building a project from symfony and doctrine

I'm trying to access the data in a fetched object. As an example I want to retrieve data in the `$products` object

```
$products = $repository->findByPrice($price);
```

I've tried `$prodcuts[0]`, `$prodcuts['pName']`

Nothing seems to work. A little advice would be very helpfull

Comment: You tried those things and *what* happened?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the namespace and use statements are pointing to correct files, then:

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('bundleName:tableEntity')
        ->findByPrice($price);
```

Then for instance you can further use

```
echo $product->getPrice();
```

You can then handle the object instantiated as per your need..

Comment: `$product` (singular) isn't a very good variable name for a collection. Also, OP appears to already have their repository so this answer adds nothing

Comment: Half of what i wrote is missed while editing..     return Response( $product->getPrice()); will fetch price from product entity table.

Comment: I've reverted the edit (don't know what that guy was thinking) but your code is still wrong. `findByPrice()` will return a **collection** meaning it must be iterated or otherwise each entity accessed by index

Comment: Yes, index is required to access values from array but we can't return all values by putting return Response statement in the loop itself. return new Response($product[$i]->getPrice()) inside a loop will print only 1st value of array $product

Comment: ive tried the above code but it started giving an error. Somehow i have changed the above query to findOneByPrice() as i need only one record anyway then  $product->getPrice(); works fine. thanks guys

Comment: Glad it helped - just in case you don't know, It is the getter (method) which are all defined in your entity table including setters inside entity folder. That's orm.. gud luck :)